# Change Range.Style on cell value change

Tags: excel, vba

There are only two possible inputs to cell: True or False (boolean). And my goal is to change the style if the boolean is set to True.

I tried the following code

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F200")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target Then
            MYRange = """" & Replace(Target.Address, "$", "") & """"
            Sheets("Ribs").Range(MYRange).Style.Name = "Good"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But I can't get it working due to line `Sheets("Ribs").Range(MYRange).Style.Name = "Good"`

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What is wrong with that line, is there an error? Also, this sounds like a job for conditional formatting.

Comment: What are you trying to do by removing the absolute reference?  Why not just do `Target.Style.Name = Good`?

Comment: Or `Sheets("Ribs").Range(Target.Address).Style = "Good"` if a different sheet to the event code.

Comment: @BruceWayne Because it raises an error `Wrong number of arguments or invalid propery assignment`

Comment: @SJR This works!

Comment: @skrat - which country are you in? E.g. what kind of Excel do you use? E.g. a French, a German, Italian? The `Style.Name` is different in many countries.

Answer (score 1):

The translation of Excel to other languages could ruin a bit the code, if the code is ran from non-English Excel and it is using `.Style` or `.LocalFormula`.

Long story short, run this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim st As Style
    For Each st In ThisWorkbook.Styles
        Debug.Print st.Name
    Next st
End Sub
```

Take a look at the result in the immediate window. In a German Excel, I am receiving result like this:

```
Ergebnis
Erklärender Text
Gut
Comma
Neutral
Notiz
Percent
```

As you see, I do not have "Good" as a style. I have to use "Gut", if I want to refer to it.